# How to ignore HTML tags using Thymeleaf when printing text string?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf in my Spring Boot project.

I've got a text string which contains some HTML tags and my goal is to print it without styling as well as without any HTML tags.

Using:

```
<p th:text="${myString}"> </p>
```

I've got something like this:

```
<b> text </b>
```

And that's ok because the value of *myString* text string is

```
String myString = "<b> text </b>";
```

So trying to do it in other way, using:

```
<p th:utext="${myString}"> </p>
```

I've got something like this:

**text**

But my goal ist to get non-formatted plain text like this:

```
text
```

Simply text without any HTML tags and without rendering the HTML code.

How can I acheive this with using Thymeleaf only?

I've tried some *th:remove="tags"* along with *th:inline="text"* but It doesn't work so far.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be clear, you have a String `"<b> text </b>"` and you want it to evaluate it to `text`?

Comment: Exactly. Just `text` not **text**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thymeleaf doesn't have any native support for this, so you're going to have to find your favorite library for removing tags use it instead.  In this example, I used [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

After adding it to your pom file, something like this should work:

```
<div th:text="${T(org.jsoup.Jsoup).parse(myString).text()}" />
```

You could also create your own dialect that does it automatically, but that's more complicated.  Then you could use your own attributes:

```
<div bohdan::removehtml="${myString}" />
```

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Use utext
Example:

```
<p th:utext="${myString}"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use th:block in Thymeleaf. it is only thymeleaf sentence and don`t rendering html code.

**Sample code**

```
<th:block th:text="${message}"></th:block>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not what I was looking for. Using th:block the result is still `<b> text </b>`